# EarPods sound problems

Tags: iphone, audio

I have a pair of earpods and when I connect them to my MacBook the sounds is more bass-y that it should.. The fun fact is that if I don't plug the mini jack completely into the port the sound is 'as it should be'! But when I put the plug correctly for 1 second the sound is ok an then it turns to very bass-y again... I presume that something is wrong with configuration or something?! When I plug it into my iphone is the same effect.. Anybody knows what's the problem??

Comment: Have you tried another set of earbuds or headphones on the MacBook and the iPhone? You're initial troubleshooting leads me to believe the EarPods are to blame. Do they sound bad on other people's devices?

Comment: Yea, I have an old headset that works perfectly

Comment: The EarPods are obviously bad. Are they brand new?

Comment: Yea :/ I will go to the apple store to check them there. I just wanted to know that I am not doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the apple store and they told me that the EarPods are lowering the volume because they have some sound-protection-thingy.... I find it very annoying though. Also I found [this link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202600) from Apple and I presume that using the EarPods with my laptop is not really an option as I can not adjust the bass... also really annoying...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have bad EarPods. Take them back to the store where you purchased them if they are new.